# Set up a development environment for MVC2 as it would be for a development team

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, iis, development-environment

So at work we have our environment setup as most of you probably do as well. We have a centralized code base (controlled through SVN), which runs off a Database on the same server (Integration). We bring this code base down and copy the database down locally to work on our machines with.

This is what I need to figure out how to set up. I want to setup a Database in SQL Server 2008 locally, have it connected to my MVC 2 app, and also have it locally setup in IIS so I can test it without going into the debugger and running in the Development Server of VS2010 everytime.

So far searching I haven't really found any articles or anything that tell how to set this up, even though I feel like it is the most common thing to do (as most software shops are setup this way).

Any sources or directions would be awesome.

Thanks!

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate, Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server 2008, and IIS (whichever version comes with Windows 7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "it depends". Although most of the software shops are setup like this there are tweaks in the setup. Especially when it comes to Database.

I found 2 cases:

1. In most cases where I worked, I found they have a DEV database server where the developers are given access on a perticular database which the entire team works on. They do install SQL Management Studio on the dev machines for connecting to the server/database.
2. Some shops have SQLExpress setup on each developer machine where they maintain a local copy of the database (same as yours)... This comes with additional headache of syncing copies of multiple databases. We used it with Visual Studion Database Projects in past and it worked like charm in many cases where we used to get "delta" updates and apply to server database. Obviously - these updates were done by someone who knew the VS DB PRO features and given some dedicated hours to perfrom the sync.

I still prefer a "controlled environment" as opposed to #2 where the schema changes are controlled by only a few...

Just my 2 cents...

Answer (score 0):

Lots of this really depends on the app and local details. But we do the same sorts of things all the time. First and foremost, you'll want your develop some standardization and/or conventions about environment -- it makes life alot easier if everyone agrees that they should be running the local test DB at .\SQLEXPRESS and if they can agree on what the local urls should be.

Perhaps the tallest pole in the tent is automating the database setup -- there are some real challenges there, especially if your app has a significant amount of data it needs to be usable. I haven't found a perfect solution here, typically we use a combination of a utility called sseutil to create database instances and a [database migration framework](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/) to make schema changes. Something like [RoundhousE](http://code.google.com/p/roundhouse/) looks compelling here.

Comment: This touches on a couple of points but I was more looking for sort of a step by step on how to setup a local environment just for myself touching on all of the points that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: No way to do a step-by-step without lots of details as step by step is very tactical here. Most one could do is to tell you to check out locally, setup IIS pointed there and somehow stand up the database.

Comment: Hmm, okay I guess I'll try and figure it out for myself.